# drupal Can we write a rule to send email to the customers on particular date

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-panels

I have a calendar module each user can create his schedules, meetings.

Now I want to send emails to the user before one hour (or one day before) of their schedule meetings.

Is that possible in drupal? I thought of working with rules but not sure that will work.

Any ideas guys please?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, rules can do that.

Comment: i know rules will work but don know how to do this can any help me please guys 
thanks in advance

Comment: Come on, you don't expect me to write a step-by-step tutorial for you, do you? Go and install the module, try it out, read the readme files and documentation, try it again... If that doesn't work, search the internet for solutions to your problem. If you can't find it, ask specific questions here or on Drupal.org.

Comment: creating a cron job will solve all ur problems
if anyone wanna to know details just mail me ,, its working for mee...